CDG Self-Transfer Schengen to Non-Schengen
I have an upcoming connection that I am weighing up on a Monday morning:7/3

(AF7371) Arrive LYS -> CDG Terminal 2F at 07:55
(DL8305) Depart CDG -> YVR Terminal 2E at 10:10

This is a 2hr15min layover - however while both flights are operated by Air France they are booked as separate tickets. With no checked bags is this connection doable?
I am not clear whether I would need to transfer terminals landside (and go through immigration etc) or if I can do this airside. It seems to me that because I am going from Schengen to non-Schengen, there will be some additional passport control in CDG.
EDIT: Removed comments about blue shuttle as that does not seem applicable for 2F to 2E. It looks like there is a bridge between these terminals?
Any insights would be appreciated. I have read the guide here which provides step-by-step instructions on the route from 2F to 2E, one thing that is unclear is if I can follow the yellow "transfer path" if my tickets are separate: https://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/transit-terminal-2f/terminal-2f-to-terminal-2e/

Would you have a boarding pass for your next flight or any checked luggage?

I would have checked in for the next flight via mobile app and no checked luggage.

I'm not sure where you got the terminal info for the first flight, but flightstats.com and other services that rely on it get it wrong: I'm quite certain that flight does not arrive at Terminal 1. All AF flights use terminals 2E, 2F and 2G only. The official ADP site says 2F for both today and tomorrow, which is a lot more consistent. However, while it saves you a bit of time, it does not change things much: it remains a pretty risky connection as a self-transfer, as the second flight is the most expensive and less frequent one, and missing it will probably be a major issue.

Yes Air France straight up doesn't operate in T1. All non-Schengen serve 2E, and Schengen can variably serve 2F or 2G

Thanks @jcaron, I was hoping you would comment because I saw your other knowledgeable posts about transfers at CDG :)
It looks like you are right re: inbound leg, I got mixed up somewhere. In this case, of 2F -> 2E, I am a bit puzzled by the rest of your comment. Yes, the downside of missing the second flight is unchanged. But surely less time to get between 2F and 2E would change the risk profile?

Please edit in the city and country name of the airports, not everybody understands the codes, besides, a single letter mistake gives a different airport sometimes in s different country.

@jcaron comment reminded me that AF doesn't operate out of T1 (mostly Star Alliance operate there)

I'm not sure where you got the terminal info for the first flight, but flightstats.com and other services that rely on it get it wrong: I'm quite certain that flight does not arrive at Terminal 1. All AF flights use terminals 2E, 2F and 2G only. The official ADP site says 2F for both today and tomorrow, which is a lot more consistent. However, while it saves you a bit of time, it does not change things much: it remains a pretty risky connection as a self-transfer, as the second flight is the most expensive and less frequent one, and missing it will probably be a major issue.


That is short, even though you would not pass (contrary to what I've written before) security before boarding. Border controls, if you are eligible for the e-Gates (PARAFE) should flow quite well.
If you land in 2F, you need to actually walk to 2E (follow the yellow connection path, map), if you are due at M gates, you will need to take the LISA shuttle, else for K and L gates you can just walk there.
Air France website quotes a average time to connect of 20-35min. And this is if you are able-bodied.
However, you may land at 2G
Some Schengen destinations can be, on short notice, switched over to 2G

Few Schengen destinations can be operated either at Terminal 2F or at Terminal 2G.
You will be informed by Air France of your assigned terminal 48 hours before the flight.

Easy CDG (unofficial info site)
If you land in 2G, then it becomes more unlikely you would make it in case of any delays.
You would need to get the Orange shuttle, taking indicated 10 min. every 6min., arriving in 2F then walk to 2E, taking border controls into accounts, this could take well over 1h to make it, if for example the shuttle is packed and you need to wait for the next...

Thanks for your reply Nicolas. I was indeed mixed up about the arrival gate. If from 2F, does it seem more possible? I am eligible to use the PARAFE gates but read mixed things about how often they are open.

@TheNidhogg Adapted my answer

Thank you for all your effort to help me, I really appreciate it. With respect to the possibility of landing at 2G - do you mention this as an edge-case for completeness or as a change that frequently occurs? I inspected the flight history of AF7371 for the previous two weeks and they all did land at 2F.

@TheNidhogg I would have absolutely no clue to give to you, I just know it's possible (Paris Airport official website destination/terminal list)

I have a hard time following the link between the explanation and the conclusion. If I understand you correctly, you expect the transfer to take about 1h from 2G and half that from 2F? If that's the case, 2h15 doesn't seem “extremely” short. It's more than enough and even leaves a bit of buffer for a short (15-30 min) delay. Obviously, if the incoming plane is one hour late or more, you would be in trouble but that's a given with a self-transfer.

@TheNidhogg As far as I know 2G is only used for the smaller turboprops and regional jets. Air France does not operate any of those themselves, only subsidiaries/affiliate flights use those. So your specific flight, which is an actual AF flight using a 320 shouldn't be an issue. I just found out that on that route there are also flights operated by Hop! (AF affiliate, using regional jets, which would indeed probably go to 2G), but unless your flight is outright cancelled and you are moved to another flight (and you have a bigger problem), I don't quite them switching you there.

The terminal info you originally had (landing at T1) is probably wrong. Some sources (like flightstats.com and a number of services that use it) do indeed state Terminal 1 for that flight, but as far as I know, Air France does not use Terminal 1 at all, with all flights at 2E, 2F and 2G. The official ADP website and Air France's website say 2F for today and the near future, which is consistent with the type of flight.
This makes things slightly easier and shorter, but overall it does not change things much.
I'll take for granted that you can actually get your boarding pass in advance/on your mobile, but even if you don't you should be able to get it from transfer desks/kiosks.
You will have to go through exit passport control (you can use the automatic gates if you are eligible). The AF website says you don't need to go through security, but I'm not confident this is always the case, as for instance the automated people mover between K, L and M is outside security.
The exact path depends on which concourse you use (K, L or M gates). DL8305 is really AF374. It often leaves from L gates, but recent history shows K and M gates as well, I'm not sure you'll be able to know far in advance.
If you leave from L gates then there is a connecting passage between 2F and L (on the 2F departures level, but I believe there's a shortcut to get there from 2F arrivals, before getting to baggage claim). You will go through passport control there, I'm not sure if you have to go through security.
If you leave from M gates I think you take the same route to L, then go down to the automated people mover to get to M, and you'll go through security there.
If you leave from K gates then there's a weird passage from arrivals (before baggage claim), where you go on a bridge over baggage claim and then on to 2E. I think you'll go through passport control there, and the idea is that you can bypass security, but I don't know the details.
The Air France web site says it takes 25 to 35 minutes on average from 2E to 2F. Not quite sure this is realistic. The ADP web site says 25 minutes to gates K and L and 35 to gates M. But they say "travel times", which probably doesn't include passport control or security, if you need to go through it (nearly certain this is the case for M gates). Of course it will vary based on:

The exact departure and arrival gates
Your walking speed
Whether you have status (and can thus use fast track aka "Accès n°1")
Queues

If all goes well, you can most definitely do it, with time to spare, probably around an hour of buffer.
The issue is that if there are any delays exceeding that and you miss your connecting flight, you will be considered a no show, and most likely your ticket will be cancelled (including the return flight, if any), and you will have to buy a new ticket, at last minute prices. Since that flight is the most expensive of the two, and the least frequent one (there's only one non-stop per day, and not every day, so you'll have to either take an indirect route or stay overnight), the inconvenience if you miss it is quite high.
I'm not sure I would personally be comfortable with that option, unless I have a ticket flexible enough that I can change it to a later (indirect) flight if needed, but don't forget that flight changes will incur a price difference (based on the current price, not the price at the time you booked originally), and that you'll most likely only be able to reroute on AF/DL/KL flights (so probably via AMS and/or SEA).
The other way around (with lots of relatively cheap alternatives to get to Lyon -- I'd switch to the train instead myself) I wouldn't be worried. In this direction, the lack of a decent plan B would concern me.
